# Find duplicates using value from other table

Tags: sql, select

I have following tables, I want to find duplicates where products are duplicated but the required rule is that one must be only in products_old table and the second in products table. So for example if there will be 2 positions of product_id 6, order won't be counted but when there will be 5 and 6 (which are sharing same remote_id) it will be in the results.

Products_old table contain only these products that have null value in ext_id column.

```
orders table:
    order_id
    9
    10
    11
    12

order_details table:
order_id, product_id  
9,        7
9,        8
10,       5
10,       6
11,       6
11,       7
11,       9
12,       8
12,       9

products table:
product_id, product_name, price, external_id  
5,          poteto,       4.99,  null
6,          potato,       7.5,   55
7,          orange,       7.99,  77
8,          green apple,  5.99,  88
9,          gren-aple,    6.99,  null

products_old table:
product_id, external_id              
5,          55
9,          88
```

If products name would be the same just with different IDs it will be easy using this query

```
select od.order_id
from order_details od join
     products p
     on od.product_id = p.product_id
group by od.order_id
having count(p.product_name) > count(distinct p.product_name)
```

I've tried so far some variations but now I'm out of ideas how to resolve this, I received suggestion to use this:

```
having count(coalesce(p.ext_id, p.product_id)) > count(distinct coalesce(p.ext_id, p.product_id))
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I am struggling to understand what your desired out is. You have put your table structure and sample data here very well but could you supply a sample of your desired output? thanks

Comment: Also you mention "remote_id" but I don't see that in your tables, hence I cannot see the correlation between products 5 & 6 other than they are both on order_id 10 and they are both a potato (but can't link as the old one was misspelled).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'external_id'. In this example output should be order_id 10, 12.             'Potato' and 'poteto' shares common external_id and it is the link between this 2 positions in table products and products_old